# Applying Master theorem with more than one term in $f(n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Solving for: $$T(n) = 4T(n/4) + n^2 + n$$

I have not been taught how to solve for two $f(n)$.
My current guess is that I just solve for $T(n) = 4T(n/4) + n^2$, ignoring the last term $n$ as $n^2$ is the faster growing term? Am I on the right track? If not can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Here $f(n) = n^2+n$, what is the issue?

Comment: How to I apply master theorem with a f(n) of n^2 + n? I don't know how to determine which case it is a subset of. I'm confused as to how I apply master theorem when there are 2 different n terms in the f(n)

Comment: $f(n)=O(n^2)$ or even $\Theta(n^2)$. What is the issue? There is nothing said about the explicit form of $f$ in the theorem, you only need the growth rate of it.